# Calculate date intervals and count of days in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, vectorization

I try to identify the start date and end date 2 different intervals.

Each interval is defined as:

- minimum: the min date of my df.
- max: the max date minus some fixed lag (1,2,3 weeks)

For simple two lags I wrote:

```
df <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 150)
dates <- as.data.frame(df)


end_1week <- max(df) - weeks(1)
min <- min(df)


end_2week <- max(df) - weeks(2)
min <- min(df)

print(paste('Sample 1 starts from',min,'to', end_1week))
print(paste('Sample 2 starts from',min,'to', end_2week))
```

How can I vectorize this procedure for an arbitrary number of lags?
Let's say defining a:

```
lags <- (1,2,4,8,12)
```

and print each sample start date and end date, adding the number of days in each sample?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example data?

Comment: i edited with some random data @ycw

Comment: weeks is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you the output you are looking for

```
library(lubridate)

df <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 150)
dates <- as.data.frame(df)

lags <- c(1,2,4,8,12)
min <- min(df)
end_weeks <- max(df) - weeks(lags)

print(paste('Sample',lags,'starts from',min,'to',end_weeks))
```

Comment: `weeks` is a `lubridate` function, it allows you to manipulate dates by week intervals. lubridate also includes functions similar to this for seconds, minutes, hours, days... etc

Comment: Good point @ycw I've updated my answer to be a vectorized version rather than processed through a for loop.